# GraphQL POST query

Tags: jquery, postman, graphql

I have a POST request to send to my GraphQL server. I've successfully used Postman and managed to send and receive a response. This is the body that I sent over to the server.

```
{
    article(text:"Bangkok is in Thailand"){
        id
        info
    }
}
```

How do I convert this to a POST request in jQuery for my GraphQL server to accept it? The URL to hit is "http://localhost:8080/query"

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery.post() method for this, you can send the actual GraphQL query as the body of the request by setting the data argument of the jQuery.post()function. In code, this looks as follows

```
$.post({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/query',
  data: JSON.stringify({ "query": "  article(text:"Bangkok is in Thailand"){ id info}" }),

  contentType: 'application/json'

}).done(function(response) {
  console.log('');
});
```